# Preprocessors Directives in c++ : what is the output of the following code?

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

Student here. I have the following piece of code and i'm confused about it's output. When i run this code, it tells me the C will be 2 but i though it will be 0. Why is it 2? Ty!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define A    0
#define B    A+1 
#define C    1-B

int main() {
cout<<C<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define` statements are just plain text replacements by the preprocessor, so `C` will be replaced with `1-0+1`, which is 2 when evaluated by the compiler. Try `#define B (A+1)` or `#define C 1-(B)` instead, then `C` will be replaced with `1-(0+1)`, which will evaluate as 0.

Comment: Compare to `#define C 1-(B)`.

Comment: fwiw, it is not only you who gets confused about this.

Comment: Because you evaluate the expression after full expanding it :)

Comment: This is a good reason NOT to use `#define` for constants, use actual C++ language constants instead, eg: `const int A = 0; const int B = A+1; const int C = 1-B;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point here is that you are expecting `B` to be evaluated befor `A`. This is true of ordinary C++ code, but the preprocessor simply *replaces* the directive with its contents.

In this case, this happens as follows.. Take:

```
cout<<C<<endl;
```

Substitute `C` for `1-B`:

```
cout<<1-B<<endl;
```

`B` -> `A+1`

```
cout<<1-A+1<<endl;
```

`A` -> `0`

```
cout<<1-0+1<<endl;
```

According to the usual [rules of C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `-` and `+` are equal and associate left-to-right, so, `1 - 0 + 1` is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc use the -E flag to see output after preprocessing.

Remove includes and the rest of the code to see output of this:

```
#define A    0
#define B    A+1 
#define C    1-B

A
B
C
```

[to come out as](https://godbolt.org/z/YoT3h3):

```
0
0 +1
1-0 +1
```

The preprocessor is just about textual replacement. If you want to define constants then define constants:

```
const int A = 0;
const int B = A+1;
const int C = 1-B;
```